# Change MySQL "lob_bin_trust" variable definitely

Tags: mysql, configuration, logging

I've seen [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635245/mysql-function-change-to-default-value-automatically-after-restart-mysql-server) earlier, but it doesn't fit in my needs.

Is there anyway to set variable "log_bin_trust_function_creators" definitely in my system, except specifying it on mysql initiation (mysqld --log-bin-trust-function-creators)?

I wonder that because our MySQL runs automatically in System Start, and I don't want to change my init.d/mysqld configuration.

I think that adding some var to my.cnf would be the perfect approach, but in [MySQL's log_bin Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-logging.html), there's nothing related to it.

By the way, restarting my server in production to test this configuration isn't what I have in mind, so I count on your consideration...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[My.cnf Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/) is really vague, and doesn't mention what variables can or can't be defined by the file, but my problem specifically is resolved as simple as it gets.

You can specify directly in your my.cnf the following line:

```
log_bin_trust_function_creators=ON
```

I've tested it in the worst way possible (a replication problem led me to restart my server), and I'm happy it worked.

Comment: Using `1` instead of `ON` also works, correct?